# Is it possible to debug multiple variables in one Ansible task without using a loop?

Tags: ansible

I want to print `var1` and `var2` in one Ansible task. I have this working YAML.

```yaml
- debug:
    var: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - var1
    - var2
```

I wonder whether is possible to do it without using `with_items` nor `msg` parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can definitely have multiple variables in a debug message, as long as it is a valid YAML.

For example, the task

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:
      var1: "{{ var1 }}"
      var2: "{{ var2 }}"
  vars:
    var1: foo
    var2: bar
```

Yields

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
    var1: foo
    var2: bar
```

---

And if you really don't want a message, drop the two variables in a dictionary:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: to_debug
  vars:
    to_debug:
      var1: "{{ var1 }}"
      var2: "{{ var2 }}"

    var1: foo
    var2: bar
```

Yields

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  to_debug:
    var1: foo
    var2: bar
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use the `vars` option in the `debug` task to print the values of multiple variables in one go. Here's an example:

```
- debug:
    vars:
      var1: "{{ var1 }}"
      var2: "{{ var2 }}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. Using that syntax will result into an error `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'Invalid options for debug: vars'`. Neither the docu [`debug` module – Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) nor the Action Plugin source [`plugins/action/debug.py `](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/debug.py) show such parameter and syntax. Are you mixing it up with [Using variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html)?